# How would I delete text in a box upon the user clicking on it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

So far, my code places `G` in the chosen box upon clicking it.  But this time, I want to remove it upon clicking it, too.

What am I doing wrong in my code and how can I fix it?

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Main.css';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            board: Array(3).fill(''),
            symbol: 'G',
            deleted: ''
        }
    }

    circClicked(box) {
        this.setState({
            symbol: this.state.board[box.dataset]
        });

        box.innerText = this.state.symbol;

        if(this.state.board[box.dataset] === this.state.symbol) {
            for (let i = 0; i < this.state.board.length; i++) {
                let s = this.setState({board: this.state.board[i]});
                s--;
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="game">
                <div id="board" onClick={(e) => this.circClicked(e.target)}>
                    <div className="circ"></div>
                    <div className="circ"></div>
                    <div className="circ"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider revising your approach so that you delegate the responsibility for rendering/populating the UI to react. This will make the behaviour of your UI more predictable.

Perhaps something like this would work for you?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Main.css';

class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            board: Array(3).fill(''),
            symbol: 'G',
            deleted: ''
        }
    }

    circClicked(index) {

        // Clone the board array
        const board = [...this.state.board]

        // Assign the next value to be shown in this "circ" element
        board[index] = board[index] ? '' : this.state.symbol

        // Update the render values to be displayed
        this.setState({ board });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div id="game">
                <div id="board">
                    <div className="circ" onClick={(e) => this.circClicked(0)}>{ this.state.board[0] }</div>
                    <div className="circ" onClick={(e) => this.circClicked(1)}>{ this.state.board[1] }</div>
                    <div className="circ" onClick={(e) => this.circClicked(2)}>{ this.state.board[2] }</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: @sp92 sorry, misread a detail - does the updated answer work for you?

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work.  `!!` is a `true` value right?

Comment: Yes - I would suggest utilising react (or react refs) to render the values rather than trying to access and set `innerText` directly. Would you like me to update the answer to illustrate that instead?

Comment: @sp92 does the above help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181514/discussion-between-sp92-and-dacre-denny).